# Problem by Passing variable between PHP, JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my code I send $id to Java Script section and it returns the same value inside `<p id="retid"></p>` and I can't get the value as integer inside $text variable.

```
        `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $regname = $row["reg-name"];
            echo '<button class="btnicon btndel" type="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv('.$id.')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>  '.$regname.'</button>';
            }
        } else {
            //header("Location: login.php?Msg=wrongPass"); }
        }

?>
</div>
        <div id="DelMessageDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >
            <form action="_modify.php" method="get">
                <div id="alerts">
                <?php



                $text = '<p id="retid"></p>';


                    echo $text.'-+-'.strip_tags($text,'<p>').'
                    Are you sure for delete? 
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.strip_tags($text).'" />                         
                    <button class="btnicon btndel" type="submit" name="operation" value="0+regDelete">Yes Delete</button>
                    ';
                ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

</div>
<?php include '_footer.php'; ?>
<script src="js/extention/choices.js"></script>
<script>
    const choices = new Choices('[data-trigger]',
    {
      searchEnabled: false
    });
    
    function showDiv(x) {
        document.getElementById('DelMessageDiv').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('retid').innerHTML = x;
    }         
</script>`
```

Thanks for all helps.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: `I can't get the value as integer inside $text variable`...what do you mean? There is nowhere that you've tried to do that. Your JS code will add the value into the "retid" element after the page has loaded, when the button is clicked. But that happens in the browser and has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, or what this code is even trying to do.  Can you elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and the specific debugging you have done?

Comment: Do you think `document.getElementById('retid').innerHTML = x;` will somehow update the value of `<input name="id">`? That’s not how JavaScript or PHP work.

Comment: If you want the selected ID value to be posted back to the server, you'll also need to put it into the `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.strip_tags($text).'" />` hidden field **using JavaScript**. `value="'.strip_tags($text).'"` won't achieve it, because that code ran when your page was first loading, while PHP was still executing on the server, which is **before** the  user clicked on anything.

Comment: Make sure you understand the lifecycle of your page and your server application, and the difference between JS and PHP. Required reading: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)